# Winbox MikroTik

Tags: mikrotik

При попытке зайти через winbox по маку микрота - заходит и если ничего не нажимать, то работает, но если попытаться открыть любой пункт меню, то в нём пусто и спустя несколько секунд выкидывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке зайти через winbox по IP - висит на Logging in:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Успешно заходит через web, но это небезопасно.

Версия winbox 3.20
Версия микрота 6.46.2 (stable)
Новых обновлений для них нет.

Comment: А логи - молчат? Проблема появилась после обновления, или "вдруг"? попробуйте откатиться на ближайшую long-term (6.44.6) или предыдущую stable.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема крылась в разрешённых ip для сервиса winbox ip-services.